# VMWare Fusion Mac 4.1.3 unable to open .vmdk

Tags: vmware, virtual-machine, vmware-fusion

I am still working with VMWARE Fusion 4.1.3 which worked fine for a long time.

From one day to the other I got the Strange Error comparable to http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=1004232

unable to open file "/.../LION.vmdk". The system cannot find the file specified.

If only one VM would have this problem i would have guessed that its a data error. But all the VMs I had till yesterday now have this starting error.

I even tried to set chmod 777 to all the files and did a "cat" command in the terminal in order to see if there is a path error.

At the moment I really have no clue how to fix this. I tried an older Time machine Backup from a few days ago but still the same problem!

I think when I would reinstall the Machine everyhting would work fine. But I really need to find out what the problem is in order to prevent it for the future.

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I found the reason!

The VMs where all created / copied from a LION Master VM.

I moved this Master VM so the corresponding "original" files weren't found anymore. Sadly the Error Message isn't really helping in finding this reason.

Hopefully my answer will help others in solving this problem faster ;)